# How to know if an image is created using OpenCV in Python?

Tags: python, opencv

I'm in a situation where I need to identify different kinds of input, including files, folders, images, etc. In case of images, I need to specifically know if an image is created using OpenCV (for the fact that it may be BGR), or any other types of images.

I noticed images created using `skimage.io.imread`, `matplotlib.pyplot.imread`, and opencvs `cv2.imread()`, are all `numpy.ndarray`, and there is no way I can distinguish between them.

I tried to use OpenCV's `cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)` on the input image, hoping the non-OpenCV images would cause an exception and thus I can identify if the image is OpenCV's or not.

Unfortunately only `PIL`, images fail this this and both `matplotlib`s and `skimage`s run just fine (they change from `RGB` to `BGR` so that's not good either).

I tried to find the underlying dtype, but they are all the same (uint8). I tried to find an attribute specific to OpenCV so others can't have it, so by querying that attribute, I may be able to know if that's an OpenCV image to no avail!

I only receive an object from the input and in case of images, there is no way of knowing in advance, what was the source of the sent image (was it read using OpenCV? should I use the conversion to `RGB`, or else, you get the idea and down the pipeline, each input has its own set of operations to execute.

**Update:**

Using `type()`, I can distinguish between all images except `matplotlib`s and `opencv`s. I can't seem to find a way to distinguish between these two!

Comment: I am almost sure you cant do that. These libraries are designed to be interoperable, so you can use the output from one and use it as input in another. But why do you want to do this? Can't you somehow distinguish them by shape, content or something else? Why do you want to now how they were created?

Comment: As I said, each of them has unique pipelines to go.

Comment: What has to pipeline they go down to do with how they were created? And is that really the only factor? This smells like an [X-Y-Problem](http://xyproblem.info/).

Comment: a simple case is that, the opencv images are in bgr, and the rest are in rgb(some are rgba! but thats not an issue). you cant blindly use them interchagably. specially if  they are being fed to models expecting rgb or vice versa.

Comment: Where do you get these images? Are they all the same size? Is there no other common trend between these images except how they were created?

Comment: Images can be of any size and they come form different sources. I couldnt find one so far!

Comment: as for me source should convert BGR ot RGB before it sends it as output - or it should add extra information that data uses BGR. It is the only way to do it.

Comment: @furas : Thats what I proposed, but we dont have any control on the sources yet. so far, its denied. I need to find a way to get this information myself.

Comment: "created using OpenCV" ... "for the fact that it may be BGR" -- huh? OpenCV only uses BGR internally in `imread`/`imwrite`. e.g. you pass a BGR numpy array to `imwrite` and it writes (for example) RGB PNG file. And vice versa. If you have PNGs with flipped channels, then the program that creates them is buggy.

Comment: The more I read into this, the more I'm confused. "noticed images created using `imread`..." -- so this is already in some script, where there are for some reason 3 different implementations of image loading using different libraries? And they return images as different types and in inconsistent colour space? Why not fix that code to something sensible?

Comment: @DanMašek : I'm not the one using imread/imwrite. one of the sources, may pretty much use it and send an BGR images to me. I cant have assumption about them, specifically send an RGB image. that would be great, but its not possible at the moment as I have said before.

Comment: @DanMašek : There is not some script! I am accounting for all possible ways the sources can send  their data. thats why I mentioned them, as `I` tried to find a way to distiguish between all these methods.

Comment: What are the sources?

Comment: different identies in the network.

Comment: Whats the downvote for ? this is redicoulous!

Comment: What are identities? How do you get send these images?

Comment: There is a centeral node, different sources, connect to it, it accepts their input and based on the type identified, each redirect to a specific pipeline. the sources are very diverse and I cant have any assumptions.

Comment: How do you get send these images? In what form? Could you post your code till now?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/207931/discussion-between-megaing-and-rika).

Comment: Would you care to explain why thats necessary? the specification is clear.

Comment: @Rika Numpy arrays don't hold any information about what the data represents. Writing a program, you need to keep track of this yourself. In case of an interface which would accept a numpy array, you either need to be explicit about what exactly it holds, or provide some means to pass the relevant information along. | If you just get sent a random 3 channel numpy array, it could really be anything -- garbage in, garbage out.

Comment: @DanMašek : You are right. I completely missed that part. thanks a lot for your generous help. both of you Thank you very much. really appreciate it

Comment: @Rika No problem. Technically (at least with the version of matplotlib I tried it with), there are some subtle internal differences between the two numpy arrays. The one coming from OpenCV has `.data` that is a read-write buffer (since it wraps memory allocated for the `cv::Mat` on the C++ side), but matplotlib one has a read-only buffer.... and apparently you can't modify that array, you get `ValueError`. But this might not be very reliable, and will work only with the original object (deep copy erases the distinction).

Comment: Thanks, thats a very good insight and imho, would be worth posting as answer. 
This is really helpful. ;)

Comment: @DanMašek : Check out the answer, using a varity of attributes, we can actually check whether the object is from opencv, or not.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### TLDR:

In order to distinguish between `openCV` and `Matplotlib` (and also `Skimage`) which all are represented as `ndarray`s, one can query `base` or `flags` attributes.

### Long explanation:

Based on further investigation, I found out that the objects created using `Matplotlib` and `openCV` differ at several places which can be used to distinuish between them.
The **base** and **flags** attributes are only two of such attributes one can use to find which is which.
Among all of these methods, only `openCV`'s `base` attribute is **None**.
Therefore one can utilize this to infer whether he/she is dealing with an image created using `openCV`'s `imread` or `Matplotlibs` `imread`.
Concerning `flags` attrbiute, only `OpenCV` **owns** the data, here are different flags for `opencv`, `Matplotlib` and also `Skimage`:

```py
In [48]: img_cv.flags
Out[48]:
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

In [49]: img_mtplotlib.flags
Out[49]:
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : False
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

In [50]: img_skimage.flags
Out[50]:
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : False
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False
```

So simply by checking the `OWNDATA`, one can decide if an image is comming form `opencv` end! :

```py
if s.flags['OWNDATA'] == True : 
    print('opencv'):
else : 
    ....
```

based on these facts, other attributes such as `itemset()` are readonly on `Matplotlib` side and trying to set any value will result in a `ValueError` exception.

second TLDR:
so based on ones need, one can use `type`, or these attributes to achieve whats needed here.

Important note :
as @DanMašek rightfully pointed out, if the object is deepcopied, the flags and base are not reliable any more, as the OWNDATA and WRITEABLE fields will be True.

Answer (score 3):

After a long discussion, the answer is clear. The question you are asking, "Can you distinguish between images loaded with `matplotlib` and `openvc`?" has to be answered with no.

Comment: The question specifically asks about opencv. not the other way around! the skimage and matplotlib can be easily distiguished using their type. however, the opencv is a different story.

Comment: Thanks. it seems you are right! based on the last comment of @Dan Mašek, I noticed, I'm dealing with numpy and seems I cant find a way to find out if its BGR or RGB!